# How can i get the Handle of a Form that are using my DLL?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7

I got a Form that are using a DLL.
 Have a way to get the Handle of the Form through the DLL?

Something like this:

```
SetWindowText(HandleOfTheForm, 'This Program is using my DLL');
```

Sorry by the grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way for the DLL to automatically discover the Form window without having some prior knowledge about it. Either the Form itself needs to tell the DLL which HWND to use, such as by a function that the DLL exports, or by giving the Form a known/predictable class name and/or window title that the DLL can look for, such as by using `FindWindow()` or `EnumWindows()`.

A better option is to write the DLL to expose a callback that the Form can assign a handler to, then have the DLL call it when needed and let the Form decide what to do when called.  That way, the DLL does not need to know anything about the Form at all.